# Sql server management studio not erroring out

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL server 2008  DB, MyDB, in production region . I restored a copy of this in dev region and renamed it to MyDBTest.

I have an Sp which refers this MyDB . So in Dev region, I changed the reference to MyDB to MyDBTest. Apart from that , I  made some other changes in the Sp.

While moving this altered SP to production, I forgot rename the MyDBTest to MYDB. This Altered SP script  is executed in production DB without fail. But obviously the query won't return any value because there is no such DB named MyDBTest in prod region.
I am wondering why this SP script did not fail when I executed the alter script in Prod environment.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a MyDBTest in production? What is the full sproc? Do you have error catching of some sort around the query in question? How are you calling the sproc? Is there error catching around the calling code?

Comment: You mean you did something like `CREATE PROC P AS EXEC NoSuchDb.dbo.NoSuchProc` and you expected it to raise an error? It should have given you a warning like `The module 'P' depends on the missing object 'NoSuchDb.dbo.NoSuchProc'. The module will still be created; however, it cannot run successfully until the object exists.`

Comment: Brian /Martin, There is no DB MyDBTest in prod. It is just a renamed version of MyDB hosted in Dev region. There was already a  MYDB in dev too but used by other development  teams. So I restored  MyDB and renamed it MyDBTest for my development purposes. In prod region,  I am getting the error saying that there is no MYDBTest while i am executing the SP. This was obvious. My question was , how could I promote this SP in Dev referring to MYDBTest to prod region ?